# One vertical div next to 3 stacked horizontal divs

Tags: html, css

That is pretty much the effect I am trying to achieve

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>

#one{
    width:80%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:red;
    float: right;

}
#two{
    width:80%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color:black;
    float: right;
}
#three{

    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;

}
#wrap{
    width: 900px;
    height: 60px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m5u4u89f/

But is there any way to do this without wrapper div with set height for all of them? because the thrid div is supposed to have the same height as all the other divs combined.

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/npo5Lqna/

Comment: pretty much but is this the best design? it would create dozens of tables on my site

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best design or not, but it's simple and works. Let's see if others have different ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to using table like @Khanh_TO did, you could use flex.

```css
.thing{
 flex:1;
 background-color:red;
}
.thing:hover{
 background-color:darkred;
}
#three{
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
}
#wrap{
 display:flex;
 flex:1;
 height:100px;
}
#wrapper{
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="three"><p style="transform: rotate(270deg);">text</p></div>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
  <div class="thing"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one more question I should have mentioned it in question. The design has to be responsive I just tried table and I'm not really capable of making that responsive. By that I mean i want to squeeze horizontal divs when resizing.

Comment: So you have a total height, #three fills the height, and the rest of the divs should evenly share the height? If so look at my edited answer.

Comment: One last thing let's say i have vertical text on this left vertical column using  transform: rotate(270deg); is there any way to squeeze the width of that column to not be wider than text itself?

Comment: Yeah, remove the width and then rotate the p tag. As shown :)